# org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory cannot be cast to javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory

Tags: jms

I have integrated JMS in my project and getting the Exception as  `ActiveMQConnectionFactory cannot be cast to javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory` while calling the `JMS receiver` from servletcontext listener but it works fine from `public static void main` method and able to receive message from queue asynchronously.I am able to send the message to queue using `queueconnection` and `queuesession` from my web app and using the same `qconnection` approach in JMS receiver function which implements `MessageListener` interface.

Can any one suggest me what is the best way to start the JMS receiver or consumer automatically when web app starts because i use `servletcontextlistener` to start listening the message queue automatically.

(both `JMS queuesender` and `queuereceiver` works fine from  `public static void main` method and problem starts only after calling the `queuereceiver` from `contextinitialize` method)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this post](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/org-apache-activemq-ActiveMQConnectionFactory-cannot-be-cast-to-javax-jms-ConnectionFactory-td2367460.html) can help you.

The cause there were two version of the ActiveMQ-jars in the classpath, said the poster.

In my case, the cause was 2 versions of javax.jms in the classpath: the one that came with ActiveMQ, and the one I was using to compile my sources (ActiveMQ is supposed to be just a test dependency for my application). I changed the scope of my maven dependency javax.jms:jms:1.1 from compile to provided, which removed the javax.jms-jar from my WAR file, and the exception disappeared.

Comment: Even if the jars are both the same version, it'll throw the exception.  The 'provided' scope as @Lessing mentioned will do the trick in Maven.  If you're not using Maven, don't put the jar directly in WEB-INF/lib, but include it on the build path for compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there's a version problem, I was able to fix this problem by using these version of activemq, jms and j2ee dependencies.

**ActiveMQ 5.8.0 and above**

- activemq-broker-**5.8.0**
- activemq-client-**5.8.0**
- geronimo-jms_**1.1**_spec-1.1.1
- geronimo-j2ee-management_**1.1**_spec-1.0.1

**Earlier version of ActiveMQ**

- activemq-core-**5.5.1**
- geronimo-j2ee-management_**1.0**_spec-1.0
- geronimo-jms_**1.1**_spec-1.1.1

> Check the versions it'll help